# How do I mount an external USB hard drive on my Sheevaplug?

Tags: ubuntu, sheevaplug

I've acquired a Sheevaplug running - I think - Ubuntu. I'd like to mount an external USB hard drive, but I don't know the name of the device that needs mounting.

When I list the devices under /dev, a long list is produced.

How do I find out which device listed needs to be mounted?

**Update:**

When I run dmesg after plugging the device in, I see the following at the end:

```
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_marvell and address 6
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 6, error -71
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_marvell and address 7
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 7, error -71
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_marvell and address 8
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 8, error -71 
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_marvell and address 9
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 9, error -71
```

And when I view /var/log/messages, I can see this:

```
Sep 23 21:26:03 debian kernel: usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_ma$
Sep 23 21:26:04 debian kernel: usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_ma$
Sep 23 21:26:05 debian kernel: usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_ma$
Sep 23 21:26:05 debian kernel: usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_ma$
```

Unfortunately, I don't know what these mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sheevaplug devices can run a variety of operating systems. If the device is running a Linux distribution, you should be able to use these methods:

When you plug in the device, a message should appear in the system log - probably in `/var/log/messages`. From this you should be able to determine the device name.

You can use `dmesg` to view kernel messages.

You can use `lsusb` to get details of USB devices

---

Error messages such as "device not accepting address" ... "error -71" suggest a hardware problem, I'd try a different USB cable, a different USB port (if available), a powered USB hub, direct power to the drive (from an appropriate external PSU) etc.

Comment: Hi RedGrittyBrick, I've updated my question following your reply.

Comment: @James: answer updated.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks. This is turning out a bit trickier than anticipated... Thanks for your replies.